# How to structure a RESTful URI with mulitple inter-related parameters

Tags: rest, uri

I'm building a RESTful API in which the user can issue a query about a given object, with a weight attached to that object. E.g.:

`http://host.domain.com/cars?id=100&weight=50`

(This is a contrived, simplified example, so apologies if this doesn't make much semantic sense!)

The complication is that the user might need to combine multiple objects in a single query. What I'm wondering is if there is a standard RESTful way to do this? For example, options that occur to me include:

`http://host.domain.com/cars?id1=100&weight1=50&id2=200&weight2=90`

`http://host.domain.com/cars?ids=100,200&weights=50,90`

I don't like the second one, because, for example, weights are optional, so you'd need to allow something like this:

`http://host.domain.com/cars?ids=100,200&weights=,90`

The first one seems preferable to me, but it seems like it could become complicated, particularly as I already have indexed arguments (e.g. x1, x2) meaning I'll need to have two levels of indexes (x1_1, x1_2, ...)

Anyone know of a standard approach to this kind of thing? Or can anyone think of a pragmatic, sensible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know if this is right or not, and LeeGee's suggestion seems reasonable, but I've ended up going with something like this:

`http://host.domain.com/cars?id_1=100&weight_1=50&id_2=200&weight_2=90`

It ends up creating ugly looking URIs, but it seems to me that they're consistent, and unambiguous, particularly when optional arguments are omitted.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure your question is covered by Cool URIs - http://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/

My personal choice, with no citations to support it, would be to firstly get rid of the query string using the server configuration (redirects or aliases), so that the base resource would appear as:

`http://host.domain.com/cars`

The list of IDs and weights could then be appended (in the URI's 'path info'), delimited as you see fit -- semi-colons, or slashes. My choice would be the latter, simply as it makes the URI cleaner to read and easier to type. The only time that becomes a problem is if weights are sometimes omitted, though that could be overcome if the IDs were alphanumeric (perhaps hashes), and the weights always numeric.

Comment: So you'd end up with something like http://host.domain.com/car/100/weight/50/car/200/weight/90 ? is that the kind of thing you mean?